# Install source code of std namespace to understand the implementation (Linux GCC)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, qt-creator, std

I want to understand the internal implementation of the `std::runtime_error` class.

The answer to [c++ vector source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4304783/4468078) explains that I usually can only browse the "interface spec" (h files) but why there is no one single implementation.

I am using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc/g++ as compiler

How can I install the source code of `std` (preferably in a way that Qt Creator can directly navigate to source code when I "follow the symbol under the cursor"?

Comment: Most of the source code you already have, in the header files. However, for the big compilers (GCC, Clang and MSVC) the implementation is generally far from readable or easily understandable. Perhaps if you try to explain your *real* problem, the *reason* you want to understand the implementation, we could possibly help you with that instead?

Comment: I guess you are right ;-) I am just curious but if the implementation is even more complicated than some header files (e. g. for streams) it is indeed a waste of time.

Comment: For libstdc++ (GNU) source code, look here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3. For libc++, look here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx. Source code of `std::runtime_error` in libstdc++: [class](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/stdexcept#L219) and [member functions](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/stdexcept.cc#L67).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Exploring source code of Standard library implementations can be extremely useful to understand how to do things properly in C++. I have learnt a lot by this approach, though admit that sometimes it's not the easiest way :).

Comment: @DanielLangr I think your comment is the best possible answer to my (multi-dimensional ;-) question. If you post an answer, I will accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For source code of **libstdc++** (GNU), look here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3.

Namely, here is the source code of `std::runtime_error`: [class](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/stdexcept#L219) and [member functions](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/stdexcept.cc#L67).

The source code of **libc++** (used typically with Clang): https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx.

As far as I know, **Microsoft implementation** is not available online, but you can find the files if you install MSVC (Visual C++).

---

**UPDATE**

For Microsoft implementation, you can use online compliers to explore the source code (though it's kind-of user-unfriendly). See, e.g. https://rextester.com/NRP17506.